# Spring Aspect on Converter

Tags: spring, converters, aspectj, aspect

I created simple Aspect an annotation for measuring time of execution of annotated method.
When I annotate method of a simple Spring Bean, inject bean, and run it like `bean.annotatedMethod()`, everything works fine.

However, when I annotate `convert()` method on Spring Converter, annotation is ignored. I'm guessing the reason is that `convert()` is called internally by Spring's ConversionService, and somehow Aspects are not respected. Is there any way to get it to work?

---

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogExecTime {

}
```

Aspect, which I register in Spring:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogTimeAspect {

    @Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)")
    public Object LogExecutionTime(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final LogExecTime annotation) throws Throwable {
        final long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting timed operation");
            final Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
            return retVal;
        } finally {
            final long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis;
            System.out.println("Call to " + joinPoint.getSignature() + " took " + duration + " ms");
        }

    }
}
```

This works fine:

```
@Component
public class Operator {

    @LogExecTime
    public void operate() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Performing operation");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}



@Bean
protected Void test(Operator o) {
    o.operate();

    return null;
}
```

But here, annotation is ignored:

```
public class SampleConverter implements Converter<SourceType, ResultType> {
    @Override
    @LogExecTime
    public ImmutableData convert(@Nonnull ClassifiedEvent result) {
       ...
    }
}



ConversionService conversionService;
...
conversionService.convert(source, ResultType.class));
```

Comment: is SampleConverter a spring managed bean?

Comment: @EssexBoy Indeed I missed it, I was instantiating my converter manually. That solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by comment of @EssexBoy, my converter was not a spring managed bean.